# How to convert entitised html tag to the "original" html tag in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

So I have the following value from database

```
$atag = "&lt;a href=&quot;http://blackberry.com/twitter&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Twitter for BlackBerry®&lt;/a&gt;";
```

Basically I want to be able to get

```
<a href="http://blackberry.com/twitter" rel="nofollow">Twitter for BlackBerry®</a>
```

Is there any helper function in CakePHP that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shoudn't be storing html escaped in your database in the first place.

but other than that it is just plain php:

```
html_entity_decode()
```

Comment: It's coming from twitter rest api response. It's already entitised

Comment: Thanks btw, I didnt realise such function exists

Comment: I see. in this case I recommend "cleaning" your rest input after retrieval and before saving it so that the saved data can be considered "workable" (unescaped).